# Low Search - How to specify a default filter for {exp:low_search:results}?

Tags: low-search

Based on the [documentation](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags), `{exp:low_search:results}` has a `default:parameter` param.

Lets say that I have a channel `foo` that has relationship field `y` where the entries have entry_id `1`,`2` or `3`

Can I make `{exp:low_search:results}` default the search to filter for `y`?

Does at least one of the code below work?

```
{exp:low_search:results
   default:y="1" 
}
```

or

```
{exp:low_search:results
   default:y[]="1" 
}
```

or

```
{exp:low_search:results
   default:child:y="" 
}
```

or

```
{exp:low_search:results
   default:child:y[]="" 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third example should work. It's the regular parameter name, prefixed with `default:`. The parameter name for the (child) [Relationship filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#relationships-parameters) is `child:field_name`, so the default version becomes `default:child:field_name`. Applied to the Results tag, this becomes:

```
{exp:low_search:results default:child:field_name="1|2|3"}
```

**Note:** The square brackets `[]` *only apply to input fields in your Form* and only for *[multi-valued attributes](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#multiple-values)*. It *never* appears in either parameter names of an EE tag or variable names.

**Square brackets are only used in the `name` attribute of `<input>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>` HTML elements.**